# Download a file without using return

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a program in asp.net C# that I need to download a file and continue running the program to delete the file that I creat, but the only whay I'm able to download the file is using a retun of a FileContentResult, like this

```
     documento.Save(Path);     
     byte[] fileBytes = GetFile(Path);
     FileContentResult resultado = File(
     fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, ""+name+"");
     return resultado;
```

but if i try to delete the file before giving the retun give me an error because i'm still with the variable filecontentresult open then i'd like to do something like that

```
documento.Save(Path);     
byte[] fileBytes = GetFile(Path);
FileContentResult file = File(
fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, ""+name+"");
//Download the file without return to the view
System.IO.File.Delete(Path);
```

Comment: It seems like the problem lies in your `GetFile` method which you haven't shown. Or perhaps with `documento.Save`. It seems that the file is still open when you try to delete it. If you provide the error, the code for `GetFile`, and tell us what `documento` is, we might be able to give you more targeted help.

Comment: `GetFile()` seems to not dispose the file handle (or anything else holds a file handle to that file) why the file can't be deleted.

Comment: Please share your ```GetFile``` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file after creating and writing in it, then you can delete.

```
using (var myFile = File.Create(myPath))
{
   // interact with myFile here, it will be disposed automatically
}

//then you can delete here
```

Comment: While the general idea is sound, it seems more likely OP is having this problem when _reading_ the file (unless they also implemented the `Save` method of `documento`). Their `GetFile` likely should be replaced with `byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);`, though depending on `documento`, OP could perhaps skip the file system altogether.